# Jenkins COMPILATION ERROR

Tags: maven, jenkins, java-7, nexus

I'm building a multi-module maven project with jenkins, reported

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error
Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath.
```

Java version

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Maven  version

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-11T00:41:47+08:00)
Maven home: /home/local/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /home/local/jdk1.7.0_79/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Pom.xml

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <name>Team Nexus Repository</name>
            <url>http://192.168.0.252:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <name>Team Nexus Repository</name>
            <url>http://192.168.0.252:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
         </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-releases</id>
            <url>http://192.168.0.252:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://192.168.0.252:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

Linux CLASSPATH

```
.:/home/local/jdk1.7.0_79/lib/dt.jar:/home/local/jdk1.7.0_79/lib/tools.jar
```

I think it is jdk configuration problems, but jdk environment variable should be correct.
Jenkins Environment Variables:

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome on StackOverflow. Please put your configuration in the code tag and explain the problem in the question, not in the question comments.

Answer (score 1):

Open "configure system" page in Jenkins, add JDK and path in JDK section, also you may need add JAVA_HOME to "Global Properties - Environment Variables".

Comment: I already set up.JAVA_HOME /home/local/jdk1.7.0_79 in Environment Variables

Comment: To Jenkins? Ok, now you need add JDK and path in JDK section. Your error occurs due to lack of major settings in the jenkins-project, Jenkins don't know where find compiler.

Comment: yes,either "configure system" or "jenkins job configure".

Comment: the comment is't  allowed upload picture,o(╯□╰)o

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider three below things to solve this issue:

Jenkins:

- Once You have Jenkins install, make sure you install Maven Plugins from “Manage Jenkins  Manage Plugins”
- Then add the Simple New Item, As Maven Project.
- Keep everything as it is, Add POM details under Build section.
- You can set the Goals and Options as: clean install or test as well.

Java:
-   Check the JAVA_HOME file version and add the JDK version accordingly everywhere.

Maven:

- Make sure you are using the right version of JDK or JRE for the compilation. (Common error of compilation come here)
- In eclipse, go to “Window  Preference  Java  Installed JRE  Apply the JRE from Execution Environments”
- Add Maven Compilation Plugins into POM.XML.
  o   Make sure you have correct version of JDK
  o   Below is the sample format

[image]